# Convex hull of eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra

If convex hull of eigenvalues of matrix A contain zero (origin of coordinate), prove that $||cA + I|| \geq 1$ for all $c \in \Bbb C$.

Comment: May you show your effort?

Comment: the problem is that I have no idea how to use the hypothesis.

Comment: Hints: If $(\lambda,V)$ is an eigenpair of $A$ (i.e., $AV=\lambda V$), what can you say about $(cA+I)V$ with respect to $V$ ? Moreover, how is defined  your matrix norm ? Is it the spectral norm ? In this case...

Comment: @JeanMarie,  $||(cA+I)V|| = ||V(c \lambda I+I)||$ if we assume that $||V|| = 1$, we can say $(c \lambda I + I)$

Comment: Dont take a norm: you have $(cA+I)V=cAV+V=c\lambda V+V=(c\lambda+1)V$, so $(c\lambda+1)$ is an eigenvalue of $(cA+I)$. It means geometrically that $\lambda \in S(A) \rightarrow c \lambda \in S(cA+I)$ (xhere S() is meant for spectrum=set of eigenvalues. Geometrically the spectrum is enlarged by a factor c, then translated horizontally by 1. As $0$ was in the convex hull of $S(A)$, its image $1$ is in the convex hull of S(cA+I), because convexity is preserved by enlargement and translation.

Answer (score 3):

First, note that the convex hull of eigenvalues of $A$ contains $0$ if and only if the convex hull of eigenvalues of $cA$ contains $0$ for every $c \in \Bbb C$.

With that in mind, it suffices to show that if $\|(-1)A + I\| < 1$, then the convex hull of eigenvalues of the matrix $A$ does *not* contain zero.

In particular, it suffices to show that the numerical range $\{x^*Ax : x \in \Bbb C, \|x\| = 1\}$ does not contain $0$.  To that effect, note that for all such $x$, we have
$$
x^*(I-A)x = x^*x - x^*Ax = 1-x^*Ax
$$
However, since $\|I - A\|< 1$, we have $|x^*(I - A)x| < 1$.  The conclusion follows.

Answer (score 3):

The eigenvalues of $cA+I$ are exactly $c\lambda+1$, where $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.

So the convex hull of the eigenvalues of $cA+I$ contains $1$. And hence $cA+I$ has an eigenvalue of modulus at least $1$, hence $||cA+I||\ge1$.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense than my approach

Comment: A little remark : It is possible because convexity is preserved by homothety and translation.